# Insert a new row in dataframe based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to insert a new row after an existing row with certain column values. Here is a sample data.

```
   StartDateTime           EndDateTime           HoursInBlock   TotalHours     Type   EmployeeID
2020-07-31 06:30:00      2020-07-31 07:00:00          0.5          0.5           A       1282
2020-07-31 07:00:00      2020-07-31 08:00:00           1           1.5           A       1282
2020-07-31 08:00:00      2020-07-31 09:00:00           1           2.5           B       1282
2020-07-31 09:00:00      2020-07-31 10:00:00           1           3.5           C       1282
2020-07-31 10:00:00      2020-07-31 11:00:00           1           4.5           A       1282
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do here is if TotalHours is greater than 3, I want to split that row into two separate columns. The final data would look like this.

```
   StartDateTime           EndDateTime           HoursInBlock   TotalHours     Type   EmployeeID
2020-07-31 06:30:00      2020-07-31 07:00:00          0.5          0.5           A       1282
2020-07-31 07:00:00      2020-07-31 08:00:00           1           1.5           A       1282
2020-07-31 08:00:00      2020-07-31 09:00:00           1           2.5           B       1282
2020-07-31 09:00:00      2020-07-31 09:30:00          0.5           3            C       1282 *
2020-07-31 09:30:00      2020-07-31 10:00:00          0.5          3.5           C       1282 **
2020-07-31 10:00:00      2020-07-31 11:00:00           1           4.5           A       1282
```

As you can see the row with * was updated with new values and the next row(**) was newly inserted.
Other values such as start and end time, hours in block have been adjusted as well.

I was trying to do this using, for loops and if condition but it seems like my code is not inserting a new row in my data. Could anyone please help me figure it out?

This is what I tried:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i, "TotalHours"] > 3 and df.loc[i, "TotalHours"]< 4 :
    # Update values in row *
    df.loc[i, "TotalHours"] = 8

    # Insert a new row after "i" row.
    newline = pd.DataFrame({"StartDateTime: None, "EndDateTime": None,
                            "HoursInBlock: None, "TotalHours": None, "Type": None, 
                             "EmployeeID": NONE, index=[i+1]})

     df = df.append(newline ,ignore_index=True)

    # Updating column values of the newly inserted row
     
     df.loc[i+1, "EndDateTime"] =  df.loc[i+1, "StartDateTime"] + timedelta(minutes = 30)
     df.loc[i+1, "HoursInBlock"] = df.loc[i+1, "StartDateTime"] - df.loc[i+1, "EndDateTime"]
     df.loc[i+1, "Type"] = df.loc[i, "Type"]
```

Could anyone tell me which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are inserting new rows, but you are updating the i+1 row, which are not the same.

What you may have to do is something like this :

```
df = df.append(newline ,ignore_index=True)

max_ix = max(df.index) #find the last row
# Updating column values of the newly inserted row
df.loc[max_ix, "EndDateTime"] =  df.loc[max_ix, "StartDateTime"] + timedelta(minutes = 30)
df.loc[max_ix, "HoursInBlock"] = df.loc[max_ix, "StartDateTime"] - df.loc[max_ix, "EndDateTime"]
df.loc[max_ix, "Type"] = df.loc[i, "Type"]
```

But this may not be a good thing to iterate as you will increase your dataframe row after row...

You should really find the "interesting" rows on a single operation :

```
ix = df[ (df.TotalHours > 3) & (df.TotalHours < 4)].index
df.loc[ix, "TotalHours"] = 8

newlines = df.loc[ix].copy()
newlines["EndDateTime"] = newlines["StartDateTime"] + timedelta(minutes = 30)
newlines["HoursInBlock"] = newlines["StartDateTime"] - newlines["EndDateTime"]
df = df.append(newlines)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: @alexsmith5123 : Did you had a chance to try this ?